# @ViewChild is undefined in afterViewInit using FormControl

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have an nbInput with FormControl:
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/input/overview#nbinputdirective

I want to access this in controller using @ViewChild but it returns undefined. Following is my code:

```
<section>
 <nb-form-field>
    <nb-icon nbPrefix [icon]="vm.icon"></nb-icon>
    <input
      #inputField
      class="input"
      type="text"
      nbInput
      [formControl]="input"
      placeholder="{{ vm.placeholder }}"
      (blur)="onBlur()"
      [nbDatepicker]="datePicker"
    />
    <nb-rangepicker #datePicker></nb-rangepicker>
  </nb-form-field>
</section>

@ViewChild('inputField') inputField: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.inputField); //returns undefined
  }
```

Comment: Where do you define ngControl variable?

Comment: `this.ngControl` is obviously undefined. Do you mean `this.inputField`?

Comment: yeah sorry this is 'this.inputField'

Comment: is it *ngIf'ed somewhere ????

Comment: No, but there is *rxLet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `rxLet` the viewchild won't be available at `afterViewInit`.

You have 2 possibilites :

- use a setter on `inputField` so you will get a call once the child is set.
- Use `ViewChildren` and use `ViewChildren.changes` to get a notification when there is a change on number of items (in your case from 0 to 1 child).